# MYSQL - Delete Query with Join

Tags: mysql

I have checked the answered questions. But, solutions are not working for me.

```
DELETE FROM TEST2
INNER JOIN TEST1 on TEST1.FIELD2 = TEST2.FIELD2
WHERE TEST1.FIELD1 = 22;
```

When i execute this query, i am getting the following error in phpmyadmin.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN TEST1 on TEST1.FIELD2 = TEST2.FIELD2' at line 2
```

I am getting tired. I need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This should work:

```
DELETE T
FROM TEST2 T
INNER JOIN TEST1 on TEST1.FIELD2 = T.FIELD2
WHERE TEST1.FIELD1 = 22;
```

[Sample Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e720/1)

I think you can also do it with `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM Test2
WHERE Field2 IN (
    SELECT Field2 
    FROM Test1
    WHERE Field1 = 22)
```

Comment: @user2003356 -- np, glad I could help!

Comment: better to use the first one as it won't take much time to execute, instead the second one as it is correct, the first thing will happen is that the `in` section will be executed first and store a result then executing the primary query.