# how can i delete row data from both tables with using join query ???

Tags: php, mysql

sql query :

```
table name : donersreport , register


delete from donersreport inner join register on donersreport.id = register.id where donersreport.id = '12';
```

I want to delete data from both tables...

O/P :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join register 
on donersreport.id = register.id where donersreport.id = '12' at line 1
```

Comment: cascade the table ...

Comment: you can use cascade delete option

Comment: use individual delete query for delete

Comment: @amit_183 please send me the query...

Comment: ripa -- but i want to use join...

Answer (score 0):

Pl try this:

```
Yes you can use join in delete query.

Pl refer the following link for solution.
```

[MYSQL - Delete Query with Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026368/mysql-delete-query-with-join)

--
Thanks

Comment: But i want delete data from both tables but this query only delete row from a single table...

Comment: Pl make proper connection of both the tables. You will definitely get answer.

Comment: what do you think .. this query is right or not ??? :-
delete from donersreport inner join register on donersreport.id = register.id where donersreport.id = '12';

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND […];
```

Comment: :)  That was only illustrative.  You need to replace t1 and t2 with your tablenames, the .id column names with the matching key column names in your tables and the ellipses with the actual condition for delete so you don't delete all rows.

Comment: But then you won't develop the synapses to solve the next problem yourself. ;)    But, here you go.   delete donersreport, register FROM donnersreport inner join register WHRE donersreport.id = register.id AND donersreport.id = '12';

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code like this:

```
DELETE donersreport,register from donersreport inner join register using(id) where donersreport.id = '12';
```